# Warning when passing pointers to packed structure member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, memory-alignment

I want to pass a reference to a `packed` structure to a function. Unfortunately the compiler (gcc 9.3.0) doesn't like my idea and complains about unaligned pointers. I understand what it means but I do not see how to fix it.

```
struct map {  
   ...
   int32_t xy;
   ...
} __attribute__((__packed__));

void Test::write(int32_t* addr, const int32_t &value) {
  int64_t beval = htobe64(value);
  memcpy(addr, &beval, sizeof(beval));
}

int32_t val32 = 123;
write(&map.xy, val32);
```

```
warning: taking address of packed member of ‘Test::map’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
   xx |     write(&map.xy, val32);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You might use intermediate value as workaround.

Comment: Does this warining also show up when you type "write(&(map.xy), val32)"?

Comment: Do you have other overloads of `Test::write`? There's a mismatch in type here

Comment: Avoiding the use of packed structs is a great solution to this problem

Comment: @Bananenkönig adding the inner brackets doesn't change anything

Comment: @Caleth jup, sorry, this was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, you might use intermediate value:

```
int32_t val32 = 123;
{
    auto aligned_xy = map.xy; // Fix possible alignment "issue"
    write(&aligned_xy , val32);
    map.xy = aligned_xy;
}
```

Note: `write` should not keep the 'intermediate' pointer though.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not see how to fix it.

Either don't take it's address, don't pack `map`, or accept that your program may have undefined behaviour.